# JDBC Connection Configuration is not getting listed in Jmeter 2.3.4 under config element

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jmeter

I have tried to work out Database test plan using jmeter 2.3.4 in my Ubuntu system. 
"**Add > Config Element > JDBC Connection Configuration**" in which JDBC Connection Configuration is not getting listed under config element. 
Even I have used sqljdbc4-2.0.jar in the lib path. Did I am missing out anything? 
MySQL version : 5.5.28
Ubuntu version: 12.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where did you get JMeter 2.3.4 as the earliest version I'm able to find in [JMeter Archives](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/) is 2.5.1

As per [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) guide

> **Always use the last version of JMeter**
>
> JMeter performances and memory usage have been highly improved in last 3 versions and upcoming 2.9 version will bring new set of improvements regarding memory and CPU

It is evidenced by [JMeter Performance evolution across versions (>= 2.5.1)](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterPerformance) wiki page.

So I strongly recommend switching to the latest JMeter version (which is 2.12), JDBC Connection Configuration should be there.

Also, sqljdbc.jar shouldn't be required, if you are trying to test MySQL database download [MySQL Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), unpack the jar and drop it to /lib folder of your JMeter installation.

Comment: Thank you for your kind support. Let me download the latest version of JMeter and check.